# How Can i recognize Mass Mention on a server using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, mention

like if someone tag more than 5 accounts on 1 message it will delete his message and give him a mute role that i have on the server

i search the internet for that and didn't find a solution please help

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.raw_mentions

Comment: Adding on Joshua take the `len()` of that list to get the number of mentions